# SBS 2011 fine until you login - Crash

Tags: login, windows-sbs-2011, server-crashes

Never come across this one in my time with SBS 2011.

The server boots up fine to the Ctrl Alt Del screen.  If you leave it there all email etc works fine, but if you login the screen goes black and the BIOS screen is displayed - it's reboot booting ungracefully.

Tried a different login -the same effect.
Tried Remote Desktop - the same effect.

Some remote (RSAT) tools in Windows 10 work fine but none will give me access to the Desktop so that I can run MSConfig and Disable bootup items and non-Microsoft Services.

In the EventViewer the last thing before the Crash is

> Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.

Tried Safe Mode but unable to login - No Netlogon service running.

The reason for the initial reboot was some window updates had gone on and it was asking for a reboot.

At a loss.

Thanks
John.

**12/03/19**
Update - Came in early this morning and activated the Task to uninstall the last 3 Windows Updates installed on the Server. The Server did a graceful reboot and the PowerShell command:

`Get-Hotfix -computername "SBSServer" | Select HotfixID, InstalledOn | Where-Object { $_.HotfixID -eq "kb4459934" } | Sort-Object InstalledOn`

is now not showing them installed. Have not dared try to login, this will be done on Sunday - another crash this morning would be inconvenient.

I am taking today to duplicate critical Documents/ artwork/ accounts etc to a USB Drive, we have a native server backup but if I can have it in RAW form as well......

At the same time the migration to Exchange Online is progressing.

Comment: Is the SBS server the only DC in the domain? Is the company using Exchange Server or Sharepoint Server on the SBS server? File shares? Print shares? How many users would be affected if the SBS server died?

Comment: Only Server in the building so DC, Exchange, File Shares and although it's running we don't make use of Sharepoint.  No Print Share. It's business critical so dying not an option.

I am progressing with the plan we had to move Exchange to Online and we had planned for another server this Year.

Have found in the EventViewer\Setup that the 3 updates installed before reboot were KB4486565, KB4486459 & KB4459934 - Searching for issues caused by these update returned zero.

Would be nice to uninstall them to see if it fixes but without desktop access I don't see how I can.

John.

Comment: My suggestion would be to deploy a new DC as quickly as you can and to accelerate your move to Office 365/EOL You can try this to remotelt uninstall the KB's - https://it-db.com/uninstall-kb-update-remote-computer-domain/

Comment: Hi Joe,
I found the uninstall of Updates a few mins ago and have scheduled them using a .cmd and Task Scheduler (connected to the Server).

I will hang around after work to check it executes and then do a graceful reboot of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of Updates KB4486565/ KB4486459 & KB4459934 was successful and the server rebooted gracefully.  I waited until last Sunday to try login in - Success, no ungraceful reboot.

I'm away next week, so as to not tempt fate I will not be doing any more work on the server.
Prices for a replacement server are in the pipeline.  It would seem I need the New server as a secondary AD before I can migrate our SBS Exchange to Exchange Online, this is because the Azure Connect is not compatible with SBS 2011.

John.